# problem implementing simple linked list in c++, no output

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list

For my C++ programming course, my task is to implement a simple linked list using my own functions of `addElement()`, `printList()` and `deleteList()`.

When I compile and run the following program, nothing happens. I get no warnings and using valgrind I couldn't find anything wrong.

The program code I am working with is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node(int i) : data(i), next(nullptr) {}
  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Node &n) {
    os << "Node\n"
       << "\tdata: " << n.data << "\n\tthis: " << &n << "\n\tnext: " << n.next;
    return os;
  }
};

void addElement(Node **head, int data);
void printList(Node *head);
void deleteList(Node *head);

void deleteList(Node *head) {
  Node *next = head;
  while (next) {
    Node *deleteMe = next;
    next = next->next;
    delete deleteMe;
  }
}

void addElement(Node **head, int data) {
  Node *n = new Node(data);
  n->next = *head;
  head = &n;
}

void printList(Node *head) {
  Node *next = head;
  while(next) {
    cout << next->data;
    next = next->next;
  }
}

int main() {
  Node *list = nullptr;
  addElement(&list, 1);
  addElement(&list, 2);
  addElement(&list, 3);
  addElement(&list, 4);
  printList(list);
  deleteList(list);
  return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why my code does not work and produce output.
Please help and kind regards

Comment: `addElement` modifies the value of the local variable `head`. This change is not visible to the caller. `list` is still `nullptr`.

Comment: Probably want `*head = n`

Comment: There are so many problems in your code!  Your `operator<<` goes to infinite recursion, for one thing.  In fact, you never check for `nullptr`, while you should do it all the time. This is not the only problem, there are many others.

Comment: @user31264, given the initial setting to nullptr and the fact adding is done at the start of the list, I'm not sure that nullptr checking is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
void addElement(Node **head, int data) {
  Node *n = new Node(data);
  n->next = *head;
  head = &n;
}
```

Wrong in a couple of ways:

- `head` is a *local* variable in this function, changing it will have no effect on the outside world, you should be changing `*head`; and
- `n` is *already* a pointer to a node, you should use it directly, rather than using the address of it.

In other words, that final line of code should be:

```
*head = n;
```

---

And, a few other points. First, you can avoid all those double-pointer issues prevalent in C if you just learn to use references in C++, that's one of the great advantages of the latter language. Your code then becomes:

```
void addElement(Node *&head, int data) {
  Node *n = new Node(data);
  n->next = head;
  head = n;
}

// Call with: "addElement(list, 1)".
```

Second, if you want your items appended to the *end* of the list (a more usual requirement), you can do that in a couple of ways. The first is the search for the final one then append it after there:

```
void addElement(Node *&head, int data) {
  Node *n = new Node(data);
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = n;
    } else {
        Node *curr = head;
        while (curr->next != nullptr) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }
}
```

The second (more efficient) is to maintain the `tail` element as well so that it is always available and you don't have to search for it on every insertion. That's best done with a split of functionality into separate `List` and `Node` classes, such as with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int i) : data(i), next(nullptr) {}
};

struct List {
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    List() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
};

void deleteList(List *&list) {
    Node *curr = list->head;
    while (curr != nullptr) {
        Node *deleteMe = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        delete deleteMe;
    }
    delete list;
    list = nullptr;
}

void addElement(List *list, int data) {
    Node *n = new Node(data);
    if (list->head == nullptr) {
        list->head = list->tail = n;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = n;
        list->tail = n;
    }
}

void printList(List *list) {
    Node *curr = list->head;
    while (curr != nullptr) {
        cout << curr->data;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    List *list = new List();

    addElement(list, 1);
    addElement(list, 2);
    addElement(list, 3);
    addElement(list, 4);

    printList(list);

    deleteList(list);

    return 0;
}
```

---

And, finally, though I realise you're still a relative beginner, you should at least be *aware* of the benefits of encapsulation (information hiding). A proper implementation would have the data in each class as *private* members, modifiable only by functions within the class itself (although at the request of outside callers, of course).

As it stands at the moment, I could write code that could easily modify the internal data of your class (`data` and `next`), causing serious issues. If the internal data was private, you could better protect against that.

Although I wouldn't suggest using this code for your assignment (assuming this is educational work), I'll include it anyway for your examination:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

// Only used within List and private there so leave as public.

struct Node {
    Node(int value) : m_data(value), m_next(nullptr) {}
    int m_data;
    Node *m_next;
};

// Properly encapsulae to protect memebrs.

class List {
public:
    List() : m_head(nullptr), m_tail(nullptr) {}
    ~List() { clearAll(); }
    void clearAll();
    void addElement(int data);
    void traverse(const std::function<void(int)> &callback);
private:
    Node *m_head;
    Node *m_tail;
};

// Clear all items in list.

void List::clearAll() {
    Node *curr = m_head;
    while (curr != nullptr) {
        Node *deleteMe = curr;
        curr = curr->m_next;
        delete deleteMe;
    }
    m_head = m_tail = nullptr;
}

// Add an item to list.

void List::addElement(int data) {
    Node *node = new Node(data);
    if (m_head == nullptr) {
        m_head = m_tail = node;
    } else {
        m_tail->m_next = node;
        m_tail = node;
    }
}

// Traverse list, calling a callback for each item.

void List::traverse(const std::function<void(int)> &callback) {
    Node *curr = m_head;
    while (curr != nullptr) {
        callback(curr->m_data);
        curr = curr->m_next;
    }
}

// Test harness for the code above.

int main() {
    List list; // could also 'new' this but not needed.

    list.addElement(1);
    list.addElement(2);
    list.addElement(3);
    list.addElement(4);

     // Advanced lambda stuff for callback.

    std::cout << "Items are:";
    list.traverse([](int i) -> void {
        std::cout << " " << i;
    });
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me a lot :)